# How to access the request context from the setContext function from graphql apollo-client in SSR from nextJS?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, apollo-client, react-apollo

So I'm trying to do a custom header for the requests to my graphql backend from my nextJS frontend. The code of the graphql client is as follows:

```js
import { ApolloClient, ApolloLink, InMemoryCache, createHttpLink } from '@apollo/client'
import { setContext } from '@apollo/client/link/context'
import getConfig from 'next/config'
import nookies, { parseCookies } from 'nookies'

const { publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig()

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: publicRuntimeConfig.uri,
  credentials: 'same-origin'
})

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  let token = ''
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    const { 'toDo-token': newToken } = parseCookies()
    token = newToken
  } else {
    // error is right here. I cant find a way to access the ctx 
    const { 'toDo-token': newToken } = nookies.get(ctx)
    token = newToken
  }

  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      Authorization: token ?? undefined
    }
  }
})

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  ssrMode: typeof window === 'undefined'
})

export default client
```

On the client side it works just fine. However, since I cant access client cookies on the server side, I'm trying to use the get function from nookies to grab the auth cookies and pass to the headers with the setContext function. The problem I'm having is that I cant find a way to grab the app context from next so I can look at the request info and grab the ctx from there so I can see the cookies.

I do something similar in my _app.tsx in the following way:

```js
MyApp.getInitialProps = async ({ ctx }: AppContext) => {
  const { locale } = ctx

  const { 'toDo-token': token } = nookies.get(ctx)

  let user = null
  try {
    user = await useUser()
  } catch {
    user = null
  }

  return {
    locale: locale === 'default' ? 'en' : locale as LocaleEnum,
    token: token ?? null,
    user
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can access the request context in the graphql setContext function?

Comment: You can't access the `ctx` from inside client code, you'll need to retrieve the data inside `getServerSideProps`/`getInitialProps` where that context is available.